# How to Prove a Linear Transformation is Not One to One

Tags: linear-algebra

14. Let $T :\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a linear transformation. Let $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ be two distinct, nonzero vectors in $R^n$. Which of the following is sufficient to concluded that $T$ is not one-to-one?

(A) $T(3\vec{v}) = T(\vec{u})$

(B) $T(3\vec{v}) = 2T(\vec{u})$

(C) $T(\vec{v}) = 2T(\vec{v}) + T(\vec{u})$

(D) $T(3\vec{v}) = 2T(\vec{v}) + T(\vec{u})$

I understand what a one to one transformation is, but how would you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

D. This is just working with definitions. Note that $T(3v)=3T(v)$. So with $D$ we end up with $T(v)=T(u)$, so by definition, since $u$ and $v$ are distinct vectors, $D$ shows $T$ is not injective.

Answer (score 0):

**(D)**, Since $T$ is linear translates into $T(3v)-2T(v) = T(v) = T(u)$, but $u \neq v$, so $T$ can't be injective.